# integral of a little oh

Tags: integration, limits, asymptotics

I am taking a course on Asymptotic Methods and the following question has been asked:

Take $f$ continuous and suppose that for some $\phi$ which is differentiable, positive and non-decreasing function we have $f(x) = o(\phi(x))$ as $x\to \infty$. Then show
$$
\int_a^x f(t) dt = o(x\phi(x))\,, \quad x\to\infty.
$$

So intutively this makes alot of sense but I can't prove it!

By definition we want $\frac{1}{x\phi(x)}\int_a^x f(t) dt\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. My main approach so far has been to write
$$
\left| \frac{1}{x\phi(x)}\int_a^x f(t) dt\right| \leq \frac1x \left| \int_a^R  \frac{f(t)}{\phi(t)} dt \right| + \frac{x-R}x \max_{t \in (R,x)} \left| \frac{f(t)}{\phi(x)}\right|
$$
then the first term goes to $0$ as $x\to\infty$ for any fixed $R$ and the latter term goes to $0$ if we let both $R\to\infty$ and $x\to\infty$ but clearly these two limits conflict so I am stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.